# Using HTML Preload at the end of the HTML File (not in header)

Tags: html, preload

I have some images on my website that i want to preload however i do not want to use the rel=preload in the link tag in the header because it slows down the site..  These images are needed on a different page and i want them loaded before the user clicks the page.

So can i set the link rel=preload code after js and jquery and put it at the very end of the index file before the close body tag?   This will allow me to preload the images needed (assuming they load the index first) without slowing down the index page.

So something like this:

```
<script> load js stuff </script>
<link rel-"preload" as "image" href="something here" >
<link rel-"preload" as "image" href="something here" >
<link rel-"preload" as "image" href="something here" >
<!-- about 10 files to preload -->
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:  well i found out you cant put it right before the body close tag because then youll get this warning

> The resource https://example.com/images/image.png was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

And even placing it before the js and jquery loads does not prevent the warning.. So i guess this is not possible without warnings, even placing this in the header i get warnings using google chrome.

Comment: You're on the right track, but preload is for using it on the same page. If you just want to get the browser to cache it for faster loading on the next page, actually use img elements. You'll just need to use css to hide them.

Comment: ahhhh brilliant... thanks for the heads up :)  ill do it

Comment: Afterthought: maybe use JavaScript or jQuery to inject them into the DOM after the page loads so that you don't slow down the page load in the eyes of search engine bots.

Comment: What about something like this: body::after{
     position:absolute; 
     width:0; 
     height:0; 
   overflow:hidden; 
   z-index:-1; 
     content: 
    url('../images/image1.jpg')
    url('../images/image2.jpg')
    url('../images/image3.jpg')
    url('../images/image4.jpg')
    url('../images/image5.jpg')
    url('../images/image6.jpg') 
    url('../images/image7.jpg')
    url('../images/image8.jpg')
    url('../images/image9.jpg') 
    url('../images/image10.jpg')
    url('../images/image11.jpg')
    url('../images/image12.jpg');
  }

Comment: Awesome, that seems like the right css. I still think you should use JavaScript rather than :after because the styles are calculated in the time to first paint :) (ei. `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myImgElement1)`). Trigger this JavaScript on an event like onload.

Comment: great thanks ill give it whirl :)